# How do I remove all guides in Sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app

There is an option to show/hide them, but after I've added many of them to the page, is there a way to **delete** all of them for good (other than one by one)?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on any guide and there is an option to remove all of them.

[image: Remove All Guides]

Comment: Delete via right click method only applies to the artboard that you're currently on.

Answer (score -1):

Check out these Sketch app plugins:
https://github.com/ichik/removeallguides
https://github.com/bbsody/sketch-guides-remover